# If $N$ is an $R/I$-submodule of $M$ can we view $N$ as an $R$-submodule of $M$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be an integral domain, $M$ an $R$-module and $I\subseteq \mathrm{Ann}(M)$ an ideal of $R$. $N$ is an $R/I$-submodule of $M$ (as $R/I$-module).

> Can we view $N$ as an $R$-submodule of $M$ annihilated by $I$?

Comment: yes there is no problem.

Comment: @Babgen, Thanks, can you prove it ? please.

Comment: @Edgar $N$ is a $R/I$-submodule of the $R/I$-module...?

Comment: @GiorgioMossa; yes $N$ is a $R/I$-submodule of the $R/I$-module $M.$

Comment: In the text, $M$ was an $R$-module, and it doesn't induce an $R/I$-module structure (only if the whole $M$ is annulled by $I$).

Comment: @Berci; yes $I\subset \mathrm{Ann}(M).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, if $M$ is any $R/I$ module, the action given by $r\cdot m:=(r+I)m$ gives an $R$ module structure on $M$, and the same can be said for any $R/I$ module including any $R/I$ submodules of $M$.

By definition, $im:=(i+I)m=0m=0$ for any $i\in I$, so $I$ annihilates $M$, and the same can be said for any $R$ module produced from an $R/I$ module using the above method.

Answer (score 0):

For an element $a\in R$, I write $[a]\ (:=a+I)$ for its equivalence class in $R/I$.

How is it meant that $N$ is an $R/I$-submodule of the $R$-module $M$?

The only reasonable meaning of this is, that $N\subseteq M$ is a subgroup of the additive group of $M$ which admits an $R/I$ action (denoted by $\,\cdot_N\,$), which should relate the action $\,\cdot_M\,$ of $R$ on $M$ as
$$[a]\,\cdot_N\, x \ =\ a\,\cdot_M\, x$$
for all $a\in R$, $\,x\in N$.

Now if $a\in I$, then $[a]=0$ so it must satisfy $\ a\cdot x=0\,$ for all $\,x\in N\,$ by the above equation.

Comment: I mean $N$ a $R/I$-submodule of the $R/I$-module $M.$

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes more sense. However, this is just the same situation..